# google app engine - datastore filtering not retrieving as expected

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Doing gql.query and not getting any results when I KNOW from looking at the datastore that there is a matching entry -- anyone ?  maybe it has to do with the format of my variables?

```py
for each in leveloneAdd:
    new = tuple(each[1:-1].split(','))
    tag = new[0]
    htype = new[1]

    q1 = Level_1_Headings.all().filter("name1 =",tag).filter("heading_type =",htype).get()
```

So in my logs: have confirmed that values of variables are as follows:

```py
INFO     2013-01-14 20:28:38,370 main.py:293] new is (u"'english'", u" 'subject'")
INFO     2013-01-14 20:28:38,370 main.py:295] tag is 'english'
INFO     2013-01-14 20:28:38,370 main.py:297] heading type is  'subject'
```

Also have confirmed that entry does exit (both name1 and heading_type are indexable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your tuple, you appear to have strings that contain quotes:

```
(u"'english'", u" 'subject'")
```

Therefore when you try to query them, you are querying `'english'` instead of `english`, which I'm assuming you want. Try stripping out the quotes from your original string if possible to see if the result returns as expected. You can see the difference here:

```
In [61]: t = (u"'english'", u"'subject'")

In [62]: a, b = t

In [63]: print a, b
'english' 'subject'

In [64]: t = (u"english", u"subject")

In [65]: a, b = t

In [66]: print a, b
english subject
```

To fix it, you could try something like this (note: you have a leading space in front of `subject`, so you may need to adjust for that):

```
In [68]: a, b = [i.strip("'") for i in t]

In [69]: a, b
Out[69]: (u'english', u'subject')

In [70]: print a, b
english subject
```

Comment: Thank you -- yes - I did have problem with the space in front of subject but I was able to take out when I did the split by adding the space after the comma split(', ').  Thanks again

Comment: @user1769203 No problem at all, happy you got it sorted out :) Always annoying when a space slips in there and messes things up.